# Как установить английский язык в Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Есть Windows 10 в русской редакции.

Установил на него Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition [по ссылке из поиска](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/vs/whatsnew/), смотрю - а у неё интерфейс русский.

Естественно, первое же желание - включить/установить английский язык.

Однако, оказалось, что это непросто.

Инсталлятор считает, что английский язык у меня уже установлен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И наотрез отказывается ставить английский - он ведь уже есть, логично.

С другой стороны, если зайти в настройки самой студии, то выбор языка показывает только две альтернативы: русский и... язык операционной системы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При обоих настройках разумеется язык интерфейса - русский.

Что можно в этой ситуации сделать, если на данной машине возможности установить английскую версию Windows нельзя?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо, нужно расценивать как баг то, что при установленных двух языковых пакетах тебе не все языки отображаются, а на один меньше.

Лично мне показалось, что было бы намного нагляднее показывать в диалоге выбора языка либо названия языков (русский и английский), либо точнее детектить, какой из языков совпадает с языком системы.

Однако способ установки английского языка оказался прост: для этого нужно зайти в деинсталлятор и совершить прямо противоположное действие: *снести* русский пакет.

Не знаю, сколько найдётся людей, для кого это очевидно и банально, надеюсь, кому ещё поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо установить английский язык из *language packs* -
см. [Step 6 - Install language packs (Optional)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio#step-6---install-language-packs-optional),   или для установки использовать

```
vs_installer.exe --locale en-US
```

Comment: может `en-en` :)?

Comment: А вы внимательно читали вопрос? "Вам надо установить английский язык из language packs" - так он уже установлен, посмотрите на мой скриншот. Сам поставился при установке студии.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто запустить Visual Studio Installer, перейти во вкладку Языковые пакеты, установить флажок на Английский язык, нажать кнопку "Изменить". И при открытии Visual Studio у вас уже будет английский язык

Comment: Как видно на скриншоте, ТС так и сделал. Как ваш ответ решает проблему в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно просто убрать в таком случае "Русско-языковой пакет" и оставить Английскую. Тогда при запуске будет только English

Comment: Чем ваш ответ отличается от отмеченного галкой? Ничем.